# How to implement SteerPath SDK implementation for indoor navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am doing a project that needed beacons for indoor navigation.I heard about steerpath that could help me to do the navigation. I study the document that provided by SteerPath but I m not getting properlly what i need to implement. Is there somebody who has implemented the sdk then please help me.

Answer (score 1):

On a high level there are three things you need to do to use Steerpath indoor positioning and navigation:

1. Provide a CAD map of your building to [sdk.steerpath.com](http://sdk.steerpath.com) and have the beacon locations, main pathways and destination location marked. The service will generate a positioning file for that building. If you are facing issues with this step, the easiest way is to send your CAD file through to [support@steerpath.com](http://mailto:support@steerpath.com).
2. Place the beacons (iBeacon or Eddystone-UID( in your venue as described in your CAD file.
3. Integrate the iOS indoor positioning framework into your app. This means telling it to load your building's positioning file, set the delegates and optionally use the provided indoor map widget. Alternatively you can use the example app provided with the SDK which shows how to do all of this.

After this you will get  can request routes from your location to any destination etc.

**You also asked about how to get help:** Generally writing to [support@steerpath.com](http://mailto:support@steerpath.com) where you describe what you are trying to accomplish and what problem you have will yield an answer from the support staff.

A good alternative is also to ask here on stackoverflow as you have done. However to get a clear answer, in the future it would be good if you describe your question in more detail, i.e. what you setup is, usage scenario as well as what the specific problem you are currently facing is.

Full disclosure: I work at [Steerpath](http://www.steerpath.com) which I've mentioned in my profile as well.